# Git - Mezcle con una rama que no debia mezclar

Tags: git, bitbucket

Tengo un las siguientes ramas en mi local y remoto:

```
master
develop
*hot-fix/test
```

Estoy trabajando actualmente en la rama `hot-fix/test` pero por error hice un `git pull origin develop` y luego un `git push`. los cambios de `develop` quedarón en la rama en la que estoy trabajando. ¿Como puedo reversar esa mezcla? tanto en local como en remoto.

Answer (score 0):

deberás buscar el último commit que había en hot-fix/test antes de hacer el merge,

luego desde hot-fix/test hacer

`git reset --hard commitID`

y luego `git push -u origin hot-fix/test --force-with-lease` para sobreescribir la rama remota (la parte `-u origin hot-fix/test` puede no sser necesaria)